# Angularjs limitTo filter strange behavior with Number.MAX_VALUE

Tags: angularjs, filter, numbers

I use angular v1.3.0-beta.11. I have used limitTo filter as follows: 
ng-repeat="item in calendarItems | limitTo: calendarItemsLimit"

when i set calendarItemsLimit to Number.MAX_VALUE which is 1.7976931348623157e+308 then the result is that angular shows only one list item. Seems like angularJs understands Number.MAX_VALUE as 1.

AngularJs docs say that limit parameter passed to limitTo filter can be number or string. So Number.MAX_VALUE is number , but seems that angular interprets it as string .

Can anyone explain this strange behaviour?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have debugged angular sources for v1.3.0-beta.11. The implementation of limitTo filter contains:

```
if (Math.abs(Number(limit)) === Infinity) {
  limit = Number(limit);
} else {
  limit = int(limit);
}
```

int function is defined as follows:

```
function int(str) {
   return parseInt(str, 10);
}
```

so when limit is set to Number.MAX_VALUE the "else" block executes and limit is passed to parseInt function. Hence the limit will be set to 1